# VsVim start in insert mode when opening a file

Tags: vim, vsvim

I was wondering if it would be possible to make VsVim start in insert mode when opening a file. I have tried putting `:set insertmode`, and `start` in my vimrc but both of those had no effect. It would also be great if it set all the files I had open to insert mode when I reopen the solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you try launch vim with `-y` argument?
`-y   Easy mode (like "evim", modeless)`

Comment: This seems like a somewhat odd request. VsVim/Vim call it "Normal" mode because it's what you should normally use. I don't quite see the point of adding Vim-behavior to Visual Studio if you don't want to work the "vim way"?

Comment: @ThomasSvensen The reason I use vim is because it lets me easily create key mappings. I could try to edit visual studio's key mappings but it is not as easy. Vim also lets me have my key mappings do all kinds of things. For example in vim if i wanted control-G to make my cursor go 3 times to the right and then find the next `(` all I need to do is `:imap <C-G> <ESC>3l/(<CR>i` comparing this to other methods of making keybindings I found it much easier. I could for example use emacs, but then I need to learn lisp and the emacs functions which is not as easy. Basically it for easy key mapping.

Comment: OK, that's a fair reason. I also really like the key binding, e.g. together with ReSharper I get some pretty nice binding, things like `nnoremap gi :vsc Resharper.Resharper_GotoImplementation<CR>`. But you really should invest some time in learning to navigate your code using Vim keys. It is super-efficient when you get the hang of it.

Answer (score -1):

Try launching with the -c command `-c 'startinsert' FILENAME`